# Is it possible to make a task call inside wait statement in system Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
wait((irq == 1'b1) || (wb_bus.master_read(2'b10,DON) DON == 16'h8000));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly. But indirectly is probably not going to do what you want. (Which we have no idea what that is. See the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info))

Assuming `master_read` is a time consuming task, you can wrap it non-void function that always returns true. The then do `fork wb_bus.master_read(2'b10,DON); join_none` inside the function. If `master_read` is not time consuming, then make it a function with a void return.

But you have no control over how often the expression gets evaluated, and therefore how often the task gets called. If `irq` and `DON` change at the same time, it could get called once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'm guessing you're waiting for either `irq == 1` or for a bus read to yield `16'h8000`. In that case, you could fork off the two operations, wait for any of them to complete and then stop them. Note that there's an extra fork statement that's necessary so that `disable fork` doesn't kill ALL the child threads. See @dave_59's answer [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/confusion-fork-join-...-disable-fork#reply-38941).

```
fork // Container fork to reduce scope of `disable fork`
  begin
    fork // Actual fork we want to do!
      begin
        wait(irq == 1'b1);
      end
      begin
        logic [15:0] DON;
        do begin // Assuming you want to keep reading until the value is what you want
          wb_bus.master_read(2'b10,DON)
        end
        while(DON != 16'h8000)
      end
    join_any;
    disable fork; 
  end
join
```